# radio button checked when it's value is in the database?

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have a few radio buttons on a blog I'm trying to code that are filled with categories from a database `categories`. When I edit a post with the category `"Fantasy"` I want it to be checked, but I haven't found anything that could help me.

Here's the part of the edit.php in which I create the radio buttons:

```
<form method="post">
 <div class="categories-post-edit">
  <?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
   <div class="category-post-edit">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="<?php echo e($cat->id); ?>">
     <label> <?php echo e($cat->category); ?></label>
    </input>
   </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
</form>
```

When the category of a post is `fantasy` I want the radio button with the label `fantasy` to be checked, but how do I achieve that?

Comment: `<input type="radio" <?php if(db_val ==  radio_val) echo 'selected' ?> value = "radio_val">`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use radio input attribute `selected` and add it dynamically in the input box.
NOTE: Replace fantasy string with the variable having a current category.

```
<form method="post">
 <div class="categories-post-edit">
  <?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
   <div class="category-post-edit">
    <input type="radio" <?php if($cat->category == "Fantasy") echo "selected"; ?> name="category" value="<?php echo e($cat->id); ?>">
     <label> <?php echo e($cat->category); ?></label>
    </input>
   </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: but I have more than just `fantasy` as a category, so it must be dynamic. How?

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon you must be storing fantasy in some variable, use that variable in if clause. In the edit page do you have id or name?

Answer (score 0):

you first need to retrieve the data after you've done that you can use the checked method but in PHP with the following code:

```
(!$cat['Fantasy']?:'checked="checked"')
```